# help with regexp for compilation-mode (IAR EWARM )

Tags: regular-expressions, compile-mode

I was wondering if anyone could help me figure out why the compilation-error-regexp for IAR ( compilation-error-regexp-alist-alist, in compile.el ) does not work?

The regexp is:

```
(iar
 "^\"\\(.*\\)\",\\([0-9]+\\)\\s-+\\(?:Error\\|Warnin\\(g\\)\\)\\[[0-9]+\\]:"
 1 2 nil (3))
```

An IAR EWARM (7.80.4) error/warning message has the following format:

```
c:\someFolder\someFile.cpp(18) : Error[Pe018]: expected a ")"
c:\someFolder\someFile.cpp(26) : Warning[Pe012]: parsing restarts here after previous syntax error
```

I have no experience with Emacs regular expressions, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Note that the error/warning features of compile.el work for python, so it does not seem to be a configuration issue.

Emacs version: emacs-25.1.1 (x86_64-w64-mingw32)

Edit:
Thanks! That was very helpful. Using M-x re-builder I was able to use the pattern you provided to make the following expression :

```
"\\(^..*\\.cpp\\|^..*\\.c\\|^..*\\.hpp\\|^..*\\.h\\)(\\([0-9]+\\))\\s-+:\\s-+\\(?:Error\\|Warnin\\(g\\)\\)\\[[Pe0-9]+\\]:.*"
```

It detects the filename and line number. I am however still not able to make it work in compilation mode, as I don't quite understand the remaining arguments of compilation-error-regexp-alist-alist. The documentation states:

"Each elt has the form (REGEXP FILE [LINE COLUMN TYPE HYPERLINK
HIGHLIGHT...]).  If REGEXP matches, the FILE'th subexpression
gives the file name, and the LINE'th subexpression gives the line
number.  The COLUMN'th subexpression gives the column number on
that line."

As far as I can tell the complete expression should be something like: 
`(iarbuild
     "\\(^..*\\.cpp\\|^..*\\.c\\|^..*\\.hpp\\|^..*\\.h\\)(\\([0-9]+\\))\\s-+:\\s-+\\(?:Error\\|Warnin\\(g\\)\\)\\[[Pe0-9]+\\]:.*" 1 2 nil)`

But I can't get it to work. Any tips?

Comment: Don't forget `Remark`, which is a kind of message you get when you have enabled remarks in the compiler settings.

Comment: @Lindydancer: Would `Remark` be proper value for `Info` that I was guessing at in my answer? I did wonder about simply making that group `\\(.+\\)` to mean "anything other than an Error or a Warning"; but if all lines will specify either Error, Warning, or Remark then the regexp may as well use it explicitly.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the levels are `Fatal Error` (e.g. when a header file is missing), `Error`, `Warning`, and `Remark`. I would strongly recommend a regexp that match these explicitly, to avoid false positives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use <kbd>M-x</kbd> `re-builder` on the compilation errors buffer (or just a buffer containing the text you want to match).

If you start with this edited pattern:

```
"(\\([0-9]+\\))\\s-+:\\s-+\\(?:Error\\|Warnin\\(g\\)\\)\\[[Pe0-9]+\\]:"
```

You'll probably be able to figure it out from there?

---

I imagine something like the following might do the trick?

```el
'("\\(^.+\\.\\(?:cpp\\|c\\|hpp\\|h\\)\\)(\\([0-9]+\\))\\s-+:\\s-+\\(?:Error\\|\\(Warning\\)\\|\\(Info\\)\\).*"
  1 2 (3 . 4))
```

I'm guessing at the "Info" part, just because the `(WARNING . INFO)` syntax looks like it requires some kind of Info group. It's possible that just `(WARNING)` would suffice, but I've not checked.

Groups `\\( ... \\)` are numbered from 1, but note that instances of `\\(?: ... \\)` are non-capturing groups, which aren't numbered.

Hence 1 is the FILE group; 2 is the LINE number group; and (3 . 4) is (WARNING . INFO)

---

Here's an `rx` equivalent for that regexp:

```el
(rx (group bol (one-or-more not-newline) "." (or "cpp" "c" "hpp" "h"))
    "(" (group (one-or-more digit)) ")"
    (one-or-more whitespace) ":" (one-or-more whitespace)
    (or "Error" (group "Warning") (group "Info"))
    (zero-or-more not-newline))
```

Note also Lindydancer's comments -- you may wish to introduce `"Remark"` into this.